# ember.js: unexpected behavior of controller

Tags: ember.js

I have an unexpected behavior, maybe you can let me understand there the problem is. I think it's a feature, but I can't understand it.

route:

```
App.LacesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> App.Lace.find()

App.LaceRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    App.Lace.find(params.lace_id)
  setupController: (controller, model)-> 
    controller.set('content', model)
```

controller:

```
App.LacesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  contentCount: (
    -> @get("content").toArray().length
  ).property("content")
```

list template:

```
{{contentCount}}
{{#each controller}}
{{this}}
{{/each}}
```

detail template is ininfluent here

router:

```
  @resource "laces", ->
    @resource "lace", {path: ":lace_id"}
```

When I visit `/laces` count prints 0, but all the laces are listed in the `each`

When I visit `/laces/1` count prints the correct quantity and laces are listed correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your previous code you are returning

```
@get("content").toArray().length
```

This isn't needed since that content is a `DS.RecordArray`, and it behaves like an array and have a `length` property.

So this works:

```
@get("content.length")
```

But I think that the main problem is the `property("content")`, you must specify the value that matters for the computed property, in that case, isn't the whole content, but your property `length`.

So the correct is `property("content.length")`.

The final result is:

```
App.LacesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  contentCount: (
    -> @get("content.length")
  ).property("content.length")
```

Comment: @VecchiaSpugna I updated the answer with further information. I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks. I thought that changing content could also affect its length

Answer (score 0):

whenever you override 'model' and 'setupController' in one route, then, you need to call super in the 'setupController' again, something like this:

```
App.LaceRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    App.Lace.find(params.lace_id)
  setupController: (controller, model)->
    this._super(controller, model)
    controller.set('content', model)
```